# iPhone sound manipulation

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a project that involves a sound manipulation of sorts. I want the user to be able to touch the screen of an iOS device, and depending on where their finger is depends on the frequency that is produced (i.e. they touch at coordinate 234,843 it plays something at 100Hz or whatever), and if they slide their finger in a certain direction (let's say up the y axis) the frequency also increments. I have played with the iOS software in playing audio files using AudioToolbox, but nothing like this. Is there a way to do it, and if not is there a library I should look up that is similar? Or should I look more into uploading a file and changing it based on the coordinate?